# Scan multi rows using textscan in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have variable A which contains 2 rows string with the same number of columns as follows :

```
 0 -> 2 1.000000 1.000200 A-MPDU 1.000000 1.000100 SUCCESS 1.000100 1.000200 FAIL NO
 0 NO NaN 1.000270 1.000570 BACKOFF NaN NaN NO NaN NaN NO NO
```

But when I try to use this command :

```
C = textscan(input_str,'%d %s %d %f %f %s %f %f %s %f %f %s %s');
```

It said "Error using textscan. First input must be of type double or string". When the data contains only one row, there is no error. How to read those 2 lines correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what caused your problem - your code work correctly on my MATLAB (on version 2012b). One reason I could think of, is that your were testing `textscan` with a `string` rather than a file, and you didn't add `char(10)` at the end of the first line:

```
input_str = [...
'0 -> 2   1.000000 1.000200 A-MPDU  1.000000 1.000100 SUCCESS 1.000100 1.000200 FAIL NO' char(10)...
'0 NO NaN 1.000270 1.000570 BACKOFF NaN      NaN      NO      NaN      NaN      NO   NO'];
```

(where `char(10)` is a newline character, "\n", just like inside an actual file)

`textscan`  also works if `input_str` points to a file, i.e. `input_str = fopen('t.txt');`.

Another possible explanation is if `A` is a cell array, in which case `textscan` doesn't know what to do with it. To overcome this you can iterate over the cells and send textscan one string at a time.

Comment: is it possible without char(10) because those rows comes from previous process automatically or how to add each row with char(10) automatically?

Comment: I need to know how `input_str` is stored (char array? Cell array?...) in order to answer that. In the question, the 2nd string appears on a new line (meaning you do have a "char(10)" in between). If the strings are in a file - this is also not a problem, like I said. char(10) is the default "sign" for textscan to start reading its pattern again, I used it in my example because I defined `input_str` as a single, long string (i.e. 1D char array).